# Speaker sound has too much high frequencies and is too much compressed

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, audio, music, music-player

I listen a lot to music with my Samsung A3, and the sound is totally ok with headphones (thus no strange software effect applied to audio out), but when listening with internal speaker, I notice:

- **too much high frequencies** (between 5khz and 20 khz), it nearly hurts the ears with high RMS-dB songs, *even if I reduced the high freq as much as I could in the Music Player app's EQ*
- it's like some high [dynamic range compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression) is applied to the speaker output sound (it has a very caracteristic sound) and this is not present when using headphones

All this was not present with previous phones I had.

**In order to enjoy the portability of listening to music with solely the phone's internal speaker, how to improve its quality?**

Are there apps that can apply EQ to internal speaker only (not 3.5mm headphone out jack) ?

Are there some effects to disable in a hidden menu (Developer menu?) of Android 5.0.2 ?

*Background: I have had a few Android Samsung phones, a good old cheap Samsung Young S5360, a Galaxy Trend Lite, etc. and now a Samsung A3 (SM-A300FU) using Android 5.0.2.
Music producer here.*

Comment: If you really want to improve the audio quality (for free), I recommend one of the many Viper4Android and DolbyAtmos bundles over at XDA-developers (make sure your device and firmware is supported). I can't find the exact post for your device but if you already have a rooted device, downloading and installing Viper4A is a trivial task.

Comment: If you have root permission, try using an automation app like Tasker to detect when the headphone jack is plugged in and set the equalizer accordingly.

Comment: @GiantTree are there solutions for non rooted phones to modify the global EQ of the phone's audio out?

Comment: Simple EQs (5-7 band EQs, some with reverb) are a thing on the Play Store, the quality won't increase much, though.

Comment: @GiantTree : do these EQ (as an app) apply to the global sound output of the phone? even phonecalls, etc. ?

Comment: This depends on the implementation and the specific app itself. Call audio does have its own channel (AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL) that is unaffected by an EQ on AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC.

Comment: @GiantTree : there are of lot of EQ apps, which one would you use yourself for non rooted phone? (and possibly that would apply automatically on the output of other apps, such as music players)

Comment: Yes, the EQ apps are all using the same API that doesn't require rooting of any kind.